# Cygwin make error, I believe relating to directory problems

Tags: linux, windows, gcc

I have searched around and found somewhat similar problems, but nothing directly specific to my problem, and nothing with an answer I can figure out how to apply to my situation, so here goes.

I am attempting to make a program I used on Ubuntu for quite some time - a program I'm fairly certain can be compiled on Windows as I used to have it there, albeit an out of date version. I have downloaded Cygwin and made sure to include the dev packages including make, gcc, etc. I was able to configure the program (for me in this case my syntax was `./configure --enable-gmcp`) and that went through without a hitch. However I now need to MAKE this program, and when I attempt to run MAKE I get the following error.

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cd src; PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD APP/bin/x86_64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD APP/bin/x86:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/usr/lib/lapack:@PATH@ make files'
Makefile:18: recipe for target `files' failed
```

I assume it's finding the error where `c/Program Files (x86)` appears in the path. I know it doesn't do well with spaces, and I assume that would carry into parentheses as well. Here is where my problem is - none of the installation should be in Program Files at all. Cygwin is on the default of `C:\cygwin` (and upon looking `C:\cygwin64` as well) and the program I am trying to make is on the Desktop (`C:\Users\myname\Desktop\TF`).

I'm not sure if I need to somehow change the path here? Or what else could be going on to cause this error. I'm very unfamiliar with Cygwin at this point.

Thank you.

Comment: It's the fact that Cygwin _inherits_ the Windows path (adjusted for cygdrive).  You'll need to remove all the objectionable entries before invoking `configure`.

Comment: Sorry to ask for the baby steps but where would I need to remove these from? I'm just not seeing where it's picking up anything related to program files, so I'm not sure where to make changes? I assumed I could fix the path by putting it in quotations or escaping the offensive characters, but I'm not sure where to do so in this application. In short, I understand that there is a problem with the path and it needs to be changed, so I suppose that my original problem was more along the lines of 'where is this happening and can I change it' not 'what is causing the error'.

Comment: After opening your cygwin shell, examine the path and manually set it to something appropriate, eliminating the Windows paths with spaces in them. In your case, probably `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/lapack`

Comment: @JimGarrison - thanks so much, this seemed to do the trick and MAKE moved on past my error point, I'll mark that as a solution as soon as I figure out how >.>. I now noticed a previous error in the configure sequence that I hadn't noticed before:
`checking size of short... configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (short), 77`
Any chance that is related to my problem?